# Apache2 is using PHP 8.3.2 but Ubuntu said php8.3 package is not long required

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

After a recent distribution update from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, the `apt update` command reports that the package `php` and `php8.3` are no longer required. However, the Apache web server is using `PHP Version 8.3.2-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1` (reported from `phpinfo()` page) and the `php.ini` loaded is from `/etc/php/8.3/apache2/php.ini`. Why does the `apt upgrade` reports that these 2 packages are no longer required?

I don't dare to execute the `sudo apt autoremove`.

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  php php8.3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Output of `php --version`:

```
PHP 8.3.2-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2024 14:16:18) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.3.2-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Are you using PHP?

Comment: Yes, I do use PHP with Apache web server, along with MySQL. Standard stuff.

Comment: Try: `aptitude unmarkauto php php8.3`. Then run an update/upgrade, and see if it still mentions them. There is a much longer version but try that first.

Comment: @PaulAllsopp it works! the problem is gone!

Comment: Awesome. I added a proper answer so you can be marked as such. @Raptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: aptitude unmarkauto php php8.3.
Then run an update/upgrade, and see if it still mentions them.
There is a much longer version but try that first.

HTH